# Know where a connection to my server (domain) comes from in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a service ASP.NET Core in a GNU/Linux server with the following start settings:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Proyecta.PPlus.Web.Helpers;

namespace Proyecta.PPlus.Web.Startup
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CurrentDirectoryHelpers.SetCurrentDirectory();
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel(opt => opt.AddServerHeader = false)
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIIS()
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseUrls("https://*:5001")
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
    }
}
```

In `CreateWebHostBuilder` will step in `.UseUrls`) `to define the URLs accepted as connection ('.UseUrls (https://*:5001)` accepts connections from any IP provided the port and SSL are fulfilled`'. UseUrls("https://domain1:5001") ' I would accept only connections that come connect to that domain...).

Ok, this service will have a number of domains through which customers will connect and, depending on that domain, some or other options will be made.

```
.UseUrls("https://domain1:5001")
.UseUrls("https://domain2:5002")
.UseUrls("https://domain3:5003")
.UseUrls("https://localhost:8080")
```

My doubt is how do I know through where they connect so I can configure these actions?. If connected to 'domain3`or 'localhost'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this incidence with the information stored in the `context request`:

`HttpContext.Request.Host` return the domain like `domain1:5001`.

If I only want the domain name or the port, I can do this:

`HttpContext.Request.Host.Host` for the domain name, it returns `domain1`

`HttpContext.Request.Host.Port` for only the port, it returns `5001`.

I added it to the `login` controller to perform the relevant actions:

```
public virtual async Task<JsonResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginModel, string returnUrl = "", string returnUrlHash = "", string ss = "")
{
    [...]

    if (HttpContext.Request.Host.Host.ToString().Equals("domain1"))
    {
        [...]
    } 
    else if (HttpContext.Request.Host.ToString().Equals("127.0.0.1:9229"))
    {
        [...]
    }
    else
    {
        [...]
    }

    return Json(new AjaxResponse { TargetUrl = returnUrl });
}
```